# How call function with Map<String,dynamic>message in onmessage listen with attribute of remote message in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-messaging

This is my function in flutter

```
String getRideRequestId(Map<String,dynamic> message){
  String rideRequestId="";
if(Platform.isAndroid){
  rideRequestId=message['data']['ride_request_id'];
}else{
 rideRequestId=message['ride_request_id'];
}
return rideRequestId;
}
```

and i wanted to call it in on message listen or onresume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the docs right here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#foreground-messages

And I guess you're trying to call the getRideRequestId with the `message.data` property on the RemoteMessage object.

Just do it inside the listener function.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  getRideRequestId(message.data);
});
```

Please be more specific about the issue you're facing, like do you get any errors while trying this.